# Is there a way to use Nrwl Nx's AST utils for Angular in Nx >13

Tags: angular, generator, nrwl-nx, nrwl, angular-schematics

I wrote a few generators that were working until I did a recent migration. I was importing and using Nrwl AST utils using import paths like:

```
import { addImportToModule } from '@nrwl/angular/src/utils/nx-devkit/ast-utils';
```

At the time I think the source code comments said these would be removed but I used them anyway. Now that I have updated to 13.8.3 my generators are busted:

```
Package subpath './src/utils/nx-devkit/ast-utils' is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/@nrwl/angular/package.json
```

Is there a proper way to use these Angular utils in workspace generators?